# Scrapping Leaflet.js map using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, leaflet, scrape

I'm using the below code to scrape the click pop-up content from this leaflet web map: https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/simpel/gis/konsumsienergi

But it returns an empty list.

How to get the content from the click pop-up?

```
import xlsxwriter
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

element_list = []

for skip in range(1):
    
    page_url = "https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/simpel/gis/konsumsienergi" 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.get(page_url)

        
    Detail = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'span class')


    for i in range(len(Detail)):
        element_list.append([Detail[i].text])

print(element_list)

driver.close()
```

Comment: this locator `span class` is invalid

Comment: Use your browser's network tab to see the HTTP requests. The data is fetched from https://ditppu.menlhk.go.id/apippu/gis/sebaranEnergi/tahun/2022/param//kategori//subkategori/ .